# How to state a facts in prolog what works in both ways?

Tags: prolog

What is the correct way to do this in Prolog:

"jake and amy are married."

```
married(jake, amy).
```

this statement says jake is married to amy, but not amy is married to jake.
so to solve this I thought of adding this

```
married(amy, jake).
```

but this feels redundant and may mess up some searches.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a helper predicate `partner/2` to do it:

```
partner(X,Y):- married(X,Y).
partner(X,Y):- married(Y,X).
```

or shorter:

```
partner(X,Y):- married(X,Y) ; married(Y,X).
```

Gives the output

```
?- partner(X,Y).
X = jake,
Y = amy ;
X = amy,
Y = jake ;
false.
```

However if you define it like this:

```
mar(jake, amy).
mar(X,Y):- mar(Y,X).
```

you might get stuck in an infinite loop when called within an unlucky constellation.

```
?- mar(X,Y).
X = jake,
Y = amy ;
X = amy,
Y = jake ;
X = jake,
Y = amy ;
...
```